# Image processing in MPI

Tags: mpi

This is my attempt to code the  classical smoothing pixel average algorithm in MPI. I almost got it working but something weird happens with the halo exchange as can see the lines right in the edges. I can't seem to find the bug. Am I properly exchanging halos?  What section of the final array should I gather?

https://pastebin.com/4rtFnSJ5

```
int next = rank + 1;
int prev = rank - 1;

if (next >= size) {
  next = MPI_PROC_NULL;
}

if (prev < 0) {
  prev = MPI_PROC_NULL;
}

int rows = y / px;
int cols = x;
int d = 1;

for (int iter = 0; iter < TotalIter; iter++) {
  for (int i = 0; i < rows + 2; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols + 2; j++)
      for (int k = 0; k < rgb; k++)
        new[i][j * rgb + k] = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i < rows + 1; i++) {

    int iMin = -min(d, i - 1);
    int iMax = min(d, (rows + 1 - i - 1));

    for (int j = 1; j < cols + 1; j++) {
      int jMin = -min(d, j - 1);
      int iMax = min(d, (cols + 1 - j - 1));

      int counter = 0;

      for (int p = iMin; p <= iMax; p++)
        for (int q = jMin; q <= jMax; q++) {
          counter = counter + 1;
          for (int k = 0; k < rgb; k++) {
            new[i][j * rgb + k] += old[i + p][(j + q) * rgb + k];
          }
        }

      for (int k = 0; k < rgb; k++) {
        new[i][j * rgb + k] -= old[i][j * rgb + k];
        new[i][j * rgb + k] /= (counter - 1);
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 2; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 2; j < cols; j++)
      for (int k = 0; k < rgb; k++) {
        old[i][j * rgb + k] = new[i][j * rgb + k];
      }

  MPI_Sendrecv(&old[rows][1], cols * rgb, MPI_INT, next, 1, &old[0][1],
               cols * rgb, MPI_INT, prev, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

  MPI_Sendrecv(&old[1][1], cols * rgb, MPI_INT, prev, 2, &old[rows + 1][1],
               cols * rgb, MPI_INT, next, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}

 for (int i = 1; i< rows+1; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j< cols+1; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k< rgb; k++) {
           buf[i-1][(j-1)*rgb+k] =  old[i][j*rgb+k] ;
         }

MPI_Gather(&buf[0][0], rows *cols *rgb, MPI_INT, &Finalbuffer[0][0],
           rows *cols *rgb, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The output looks like this when run on 8 MPI processes. I can clearly see delimiting lines. For that reason I thought I was not doing halo exchanges properly.
[image]

Comment: There's a bug in the initialisation - new[i][j x rgb+c] = 0 should be "+k". You've not given us enough info to debug the code since you haven't said, for example, what "prev" and "next" are. However, my guess is that the gather is wrong - you want to gather up the *interior* of the old arrays (excluding the halos) but you are actually gathering the section starting from[0][0] which includes some halo and edge data as well.

Comment: @DavidHenty Thanks. I have updated my question and fixed the typo. You re right that the gather seems wrong, but I am confused about what to gather. Should this be `MPI_Gather(&old[1][1], rows*cols*rgb, MPI_INT,
               &Finalbuffer[0][0], rows*cols*rgb , MPI_INT,
               0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

Comment: Please edit your post and add a [MCVE].  Meanwhile, double check your data is in contiguous memory.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Is there a way to add a link to a compilable still minimal and verifiable code?

Comment: This won't work as the gather will collect contiguous data and the core of your "old" area (i.e. the centre excluding the halos) is not contiguous. As @GillesGouaillardet points out, the solution to this depends on whether the original arrays are allocated contiguously (which they may not be if you have used "malloc").

Comment: @DavidHenty Arrays are contiguously allocated. I must say this works with just 1 rank. When using multiple ranks, I can see the lines that divide the decomposition. However the image is properly built but not identical.

Comment: Let me add a compilable example

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4rtFnSJ5

Comment: @Rene This is a much better MCV example to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so there are a bunch of issues here.

First, your code could only ever work with d=1 since you only swap halos of depth 1. If you want to process neighbours of distance d, you need to swap halos of depth d.

Second, you do the first halo swap *after* your first sweep through the arrays so you are reading junk halo data on iteration 1 - you need to do a halo swap before you start processing your arrays.

Third, when you copy back new to old you start from index 2 : you need to include all the pixels from 1 to lrows and 1 to lcols.

Finally, your logic of Imin, Imax etc seems wrong. You don't want to truncate the range at the edges in the parallel program - you need to go off the edges to pick up the halo data. I just set Imin = -d, Imax = d etc.

With these fixes the code seems to run OK, i.e. there are no obvious halo effects, but it still gives different results on different numbers of processes.

PS I was also flattered to see you used the "arraymalloc2d" code from one of my own MPI examples - http://www.archer.ac.uk/training/course-material/2018/07/intro-epcc/exercises/cfd.tar.gz ; I'm glad to see that these training codes are proving useful to people!

Comment: @_David Henty I cannot fix it. Would you mind to share your changes? In theory, all outputs should be identical. I don't get it...

Comment: I was checking my code and it produces an invalid image for more than one process. I reran your original code and got the same effect. Could you give me access to your test PNG input file and say exactly what parameters you use when you run?

Comment: @_David Henty To run this `./binary input.png output.png 25 1`. Is it not possible for you to use the PNG file I uploaded above?